# implementing merge sort c++

Tags: c++, mergesort

Hi I am trying to implement a merge sort on a vector which I pass into the function. Here is my code, it does not sort the list but I am not sure what is wrong. When I output the original vector and the sorted vector there are some differences between the two but it is still not sorted.

```
void BestFit::findBest(){
    vector<double> distances;
    vector<double> sorted;
    distances = getDistance(0);
    printDistance(distances);
    sorted = sortDistance(distances);
    printDistance(sorted);
}

vector<double> BestFit::sortDistance(vector<double> distances){
    int mid = distances.size()/2;
    vector<double> left;
    vector<double> right;

    if(distances.size() > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
            left.push_back(distances[i]);
        }

        for(int i = mid; i < distances.size(); i++){
            right.push_back(distances[i]);
        }
        return sortDistanceHelp(left, right);
    }else{
        return distances;
    }
}

vector<double> BestFit::sortDistanceHelp(vector<double> left, vector<double> right){
    vector<double> result;
    if(left.size() > 1){
        left = sortDistance(left);
    }else if(right.size() > 1){
        right = sortDistance(right);
    }

    int count = 0;
    int left_count = 0;
    int right_count = 0;
    while(count < (left.size() + right.size())){
        if(left_count < left.size() && right_count < right.size()){
            if(left[left_count] <= right[right_count]){
                result.push_back(left[left_count]);
                left_count++;
            }else{
                result.push_back(right[right_count]);
                right_count++;
            }
        }else if(left_count < left.size()){
            result.push_back(left[left_count]);
            left_count++;
        }else{
            result.push_back(right[right_count]);
            right_count++;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the output of the unsorted and sorted distance vectors.

Unsorted:

Distance: 0.679371
Distance: 1.263918
Distance: 1.575268
Distance: 0.117904
Distance: 3.851347
Distance: 2.317885
Distance: 0.899686
Distance: 3.916363
Distance: 1.513004
Distance: 0.446430

Sorted:

Distance: 0.679371
Distance: 1.263918
Distance: 1.575268
Distance: 0.117904
Distance: 2.317885
Distance: 0.899686
Distance: 3.851347
Distance: 3.916363
Distance: 1.513004
Distance: 0.446430

Comment: I take it using `std::sort()` is out of the question? If so, just how much of the std lib can you use, because it is a trivial algorithm if you can utilize `std::merge()` or `std::inplace_merge()`.

Comment: I'm just trying to implement a merge sort without using any libraries

Comment: Then you'll have a bit of work to do extricating those `std::vector<>`s, because they are in the same library. In the meantime, start by writing a simple routine that merges two sorted lists into a third result list using iterators. I'm guessing the algorithm for in-place merging is a bit out of your wheelhouse right now.

Comment: It would help if the posted code were complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the problem. In `sortDistanceHelp()`:

```
if(left.size() > 1){
    left = sortDistance(left);
}else if(right.size() > 1){ //<<<===== ELSE SHOULD NOT BE HERE
    right = sortDistance(right);
}
```

It should read like this:

```
if(left.size() > 1)
    left = sortDistance(left);

if(right.size() > 1)
    right = sortDistance(right);
```

---

The rest of this is just a simple merge algorithm you can use for your own purposes that utilizes iterators. This is the simplest merge-algorithm I could muster. It relies on your data type to support `operator <()`, as well as `operator =()`

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void mergelists
(
    ForwardIterator first1,     // starting iterator of first sequence
    ForwardIterator last1,      // ending iterator of first sequence
    ForwardIterator first2,     // starting iterator of second sequence
    ForwardIterator last2,      // ending iterator of second sequence
    OutputIterator out1)        // output iterator for results
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    {
        // note the opposing less-comparison. equtes to (i1 <= i2)
        while (first1 != last1 && !(*first2 < *first1))
            *out1++ = *first1++;

        if (first1 != last1)
        {
            while (first2 != last2 && *first2 < *first1)
                *out1++ = *first2++;
        }
    }

    // doesn't really matter which one finished first
    //  only one of these will put one or more final
    //  nodes into the sequence.
    while (first1 != last1)
        *out1++ = *first1++;
    while (first2 != last2)
        *out1++ = *first2++;
}
```

Coupled with a general mergesort algorithm taking a starting iterator and size, we have:

```
// general mergesort algorithm
template <typename Iterator>
void mergesort(Iterator first, size_t d)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;

    Iterator last = first + d;
    size_t n = d/2;
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    if (n > 1) // no single elements
        mergesort(first, n);
    if (d > 1) // no single elements
        mergesort(first+n, d-n);

    // merge back into local sequence
    std::vector<value_type> vals;
    vals.reserve(d);
    mergelists(first, first+n, first+n, last, back_inserter(vals));

    // and copy into where it all began
    std::copy(vals.begin(), vals.end(), first);
}
```

A sample usage of this with a random-filled vector is below:

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    vector<int> data;

    // fill a vector with random junk.
    generate_n(back_inserter(data), 20, []() { return std::rand() % 99+1;});
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    mergesort(data.begin(), data.size());
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run I**

```
54 75 14 59 69 18 65 40 52 77 65 43 87 80 99 44 81 40 70 37 
14 18 37 40 40 43 44 52 54 59 65 65 69 70 75 77 80 81 87 99
```

**Sample Run II**

```
53 91 27 29 47 31 20 90 12 18 16 75 61 94 60 55 66 44 35 26 
12 16 18 20 26 27 29 31 35 44 47 53 55 60 61 66 75 90 91 94
```